# TransmitFile + SChannel

Tags: winapi, winsock, iocp, transmitfile, schannel

I'm using the TransmitFile API with I/O completion ports for an efficient multithreaded file server on Windows.

This all works fine, but I've now also implemented secure sockets using [SChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374782%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Because TransmitFile streams the file directly to the socket, I don't see a way to call EncryptMessage - will I need to read the file in chunks, encrypting and transmitting them manually?

This seems a bit silly when TransmitFile is provided for the sole purpose of high performance file transfer, and secure sockets are pretty commonplace. I wonder what IIS does, considering I believe TransmitFile was implemented for IIS in the first place?

(I originally made "TransmitFile" and "EncryptMessage" hyperlinks but the spam protection only allowed one - sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransmitFile is used by IIS, but not for encrypted data.  I don't know what it actually does, but it is acknowledged that adding encryption will slow things down substantially.

TransmitFile uses the OS caches directly and any byte-by-byte operation (such as encryption) means that this is not possible.

I do see that IIS7 is specifically touted as [improving SSL performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.09.iis.aspx) by doing the work in the kernel.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Is there a way to "lock" a socket/handle so that any overlapped operations I initiate won't actually write anything until after I unlock it?

I suppose there probably isn't, but it's worth checking before I write a custom solution, which could get quite complicated.

Comment: @Jamie M - not that I know of - but I would post this as a new question, to ensure you get best possible info.